# How to include style.css from SFC component to JS file with Vite (Vue 3)?

Tags: css, vuejs3, rollup, rollupjs, vite

Does Vite have an option similar to [css.extract](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#css-extract) in vue cli? If not, is there a tool that allows you to include CSS in a component JS file in a Vite environment?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.